# Huge camera roll backup but no pictures

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, camera, storage

I have my iOS 6 phone synced with iCloud. I had a storage shortage on iCloud so I deleted pictures from my phone, however this does not solve the problem - my phone still complains that it doesn't have enough space on iCloud.

Sure enough, I checked the "Next Backup Size" (it's 5.6GB, I am on the free tier), the Camera Roll takes 4.2GB of this.

How do I clear up the next backup size? The photos are NOT available on my phone to begin with, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Delete the old to make way for the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to remove the already backuped photos as well. On the iPhone

- open Settings and go to iCloud -> Storage & Backup -> Manage Storage (right below available space)
- tap on the name of your iPhone in the Backups section
- de-select whatever seems appropriate in the Backup Options

Answer (score 0):

This was a great solution, thanks.  First turn off CAMERA ROLL from your backup, iCloud will delete those previously backed up photos. Back up again, then turn your CAMERA ROLL back up, on again. Then back up again. You will recover all your photos and the back up will reflect the correct size.